# Simulating high-level LTE network with moving mobile phones

Tags: networking, simulation

I want to develop a simulation for a mobile application that will download video (high traffic) from a server using LTE connection. There will be different configurations and scenarios and I want to compare and contrast the latency.

I have tried OMNET++ using simulte library but it seems that it's low-level (physical layer) and it's not well documented to understand the different options. I tried Riverbed and it seems that it doesn't have LTE components.

If you can please tell me about a high level simulator just to connect multiple UEs to a server(s) using LTE, it'll be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.